# How do I check if there is an overlapping element before executing WebElement#click() in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

If there is an element that is overlapped by another element (like on this [internal Selenium test page](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/cbfc8809e5b20a44f9539951e37a5ce65fb9324a/common/src/web/click_tests/overlapping_elements.html#L6)), I get an `ElementClickInterceptedException`. It looks like I cannot check this beforehand, only after the exception is thrown via the exception message.

It's not about making the click pass (I can simply force it via JavaScript or wait if the overlap is only temporary), but about checking for the overlap to prevent the invocation of `WebElement#click()`. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try action class?

Comment: If you mean something similar to `action.moveToElement( element ).click().perform();` then yes. It works just like js to make the click pass, but how would this help with getting to know if there is an overlapping element? Am i missing on something?

Comment: There is no option in selenium till today to verify whether element overlapping or not.

Comment: Look for Z axis

Comment: @DebanjanB that comment probably isn't very helpful to the OP. How should he look for the z-axis, what should be checked?

Comment: @beatngu13 Agree, with the current amount of information provided it's near impossible to construct any canonical answer. But in those cases _Z axis_ holds the key. A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is needed.

Comment: @DebanjanB OP asks about a general approach to check for overlapping elements _before_ executing a click. Could you elaborate how he can use the z-axis to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't check beforehand but what you can do is add a `try-catch` to a click method and catch the `ElementClickInterceptedException` and retry the click until the exception is no longer thrown or a timeout occurs.