# Move to WebElement with opacity 0 via Java interactions API in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Consider the following `<select>` from an [internal Selenium test page](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/cbfc8809e5b20a44f9539951e37a5ce65fb9324a/common/src/web/formPage.html#L68):

```
<select id="invisi_select" style="opacity:0;">
    <option selected value="apples">Apples</option>
    <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
</select>
```

It is used to simulate an invisible element as the `id` suggests, which is done by setting `opacity` to 0.

Although the element is not visible, a user can actually interact with it. If I open the page in a browser and click on the element's position, the select menu opens. I believe this is also why `WebElement#isDisplayed()` returns `true` for this element, which is also what these old Selenium issues suggest:

- https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1610
- https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1941

To execute actions such as clicks, we recently switched to the [Java interactions API](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/package-summary.html) for several reasons, e.g., to [prevent `ElementClickInterceptedException`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58696977/3429133). (Please note that this is not about refactoring a bunch of Selenium tests, this happens in the context of a generic action executor that operates on top of the Selenium API.) However, if I do something like:

```
WebElement applesOption = /* get apples option */
new Actions(webDriver).moveToElement(applesOption)
        .click()
        .perform();
```

Moving to the element throws the following exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite.
```

I guess this is because [`elementsFromPoint()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-document-elementsfrompoint) via the [WebDriver Actions API](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#actions) seems to return a "non-finite" double for transparent elements like this?

Is there a way to prevent this from happening when using `Actions`? Maybe, in addition to checking if the element is clickable (`ExpectedConditions#elementToBeClickable(...)`), I would have to parse—which sounds horrible—attributes such as `opacity`?

Comment: Rather than refactoring clicks to use Actions, did you try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58698043/2386774)? We use this in all our projects and it works with no issues.

Comment: @JeffC Unfortunately, this is only applicable to a certain degree in my context as it doesn't _prevent_ the exception from happening in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your sample file locally and the code below is working with no exceptions.

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.id("invisi_select"));
Select select = new Select(e);
select.selectByValue("apples");
System.out.println(select.getFirstSelectedOption().getText());
select.selectByValue("oranges");
System.out.println(select.getFirstSelectedOption().getText());
```

It prints

```
Apples
Oranges
```

Comment: Please consider my note: "[…] this happens in the context of a generic action executor that operates on top of the Selenium API." I also said that I'm using the interactions API / `Actions`, where `Select` is not applicable. Nonetheless, +1 for presenting a solution I wasn't aware of. Thx!

Comment: Yes but you said you switched over to `Actions` when the regular clicks, etc. were throwing `ElementClickInterceptedException`. This code doesn't throw any exceptions so you can use it instead of `Actions`.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite.
```

...implies that the *WebDriver* instance was unable to focus on the element for one or other reasons:

- The element havn't loaded properly when you tried to interact with it.
- The element haven't got the focus.

---

### Solution

Instead of using the [Java interactions API](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/package-summary.html) you can use the [Select](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) *Class* and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `cssSelector` and `selectByValue()`:

  ```
  Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select#invisi_select")));
  s.selectByValue("apples");
  ```
- Using `xpath` and `selectByVisibleText()`:

  ```
  Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='invisi_select']")));
  s.selectByVisibleText("Apples");
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59853448/javascript-error-failed-to-execute-elementsfrompoint-on-document-the-provi/59854498#59854498)