# javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I recently updated my chrome version to latest i.e. `79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)` and downloaded compatible chromedriver from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/)

I've started facing this error. While debugging in detail i found that the `Select` class causing the issue. wherever I'm selecting a dropdown in my code I'm getting this issue.

The HTML of dropdown looks like below snippet:

```html
<div class="rd-input--wrapper" id="178">
    <label for="attribute178">Flavour</label>
    <select name="super_attribute[178]" data-selector="super_attribute[178]" data-validate="{required:true}" id="attribute178" class="super-attribute-select">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="27">Chocolate</option>
        <option value="28">Strawberry</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And dropdown on Webpage:

[image]

I'm using below code to select a value

```
Select s = new Select(getDriver().findElement(By.id("attribute178")));
s.selectByIndex(1);
```

Error stacktrace

> Javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document':
>   The provided double value is non-finite.   (Session info:
>   chrome=79.0.3945.130) Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision:
>   '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z' System info: host:
>   'ispl_723.test.com', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:419:64fe:5dea:dae5%en0',
>   os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_191' Driver info:
>   com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebDriver
>   Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome,
>   browserVersion: 79.0.3945.130, chrome: {chromedriverVersion:
>   79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b3389..., userDataDir: /var/folders/qf/x6bn9cgj1rx...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress:
>   localhost:61452}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled:
>   false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC,
>   proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false,
>   timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000},
>   unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}

Earlier I was using Chrome 75 and everything was working as expected. Has anyone faced this issue? Already posted question related to this error on SO is not helpful.

Comment: If it's reproducible you should post it to the selenium issue tracker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case i was using `new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).perform();` in Command Listener before each command so it move the focus on element which being executed.

This line causing the error mentioned in question. After commenting this its working fine.

Answer (score 4):

This error message...

```
Javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite
```

...implies that the *WebDriver* instance was unable to find the element for one or the other reasons:

- The element haven't loaded properly when you tried to interact with it.
- Element is within an `<iframe>` / `<frame>`
- The style attribute of the element contains **`display: none;`**
- Element is within an *shadow DOM*

---

The relevant HTML would have been helpful to analyze the issue in a better way. However, you need to take care of a couple of things as follows:

- The `id` attribute of the `<select>` tag is **attribute178** which is clearly dynamic. So you need to construct a dynamic [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890)
- As the `id` attribute of the `<select>` tag is dynamic, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  Select s = new Select(new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("select.super-attribute-select[id^='attribute']"))));
  s.selectByIndex(1);
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  Select s = new Select(new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//select[@class='super-attribute-select' and starts-with(@id, 'attribute')]"))));
  s.selectByIndex(1);
  ```

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB, I have tried this solution but unfortunately not working for me.