# "The provided double value is non-finite" error when attempting to get the locate an element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to get selenium to scroll down to a button in a website that has the text 'Try it out!' inside the button.

My problem is that there are no uniquely ID'd elements around the button to which I could scroll the view to. In addition, when I inspect the website with dev tools and search from the text 'Try it out!' in the HTML I get 72 results. I figured out that I need the 18th button but I am unable to get the browser to scroll to the button. Instead I get an error saying "The provided double value is non-finite".

Could you please look at the code below and give me an explanation to why I the browser is not scrolling down to the button?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import pathlib

# Get path to chromedriver
file_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
chromedriver_path = str(file_path)+"\\chromedriver.exe"

class Scraper:
    def __init__(self):
        
        # Open website
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
        print(self.driver)
        self.driver.get(
            "https://flespi.io/gw/#/tags/!/devices/get_devices_dev_selector_messages")
        sleep(5)
        
        # Get the 18th button that says 'Try it out!'. Position()=17 because starts with 0.
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '(//input[@value="Try it out!"])[position()=17]')
        
        # Scroll to the button and click it
        actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
        actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
        element.click()

        sleep(5)

Scraper()
```

Comment: What item are you trying to click on?

Comment: I think this usually means that the element is not visible... (has 0 or no size/position) Try webdriverwait to wait for expected condition of clickable/visible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To grab the Try it out button and click on it first create a webdriver wait to wait for the element to be clickable.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='devices_get_devices_dev_selector_messages_content']/form/div[3]/input")))
element.click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
action = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get('https://flespi.io/gw/#/tags/!/devices/get_devices_dev_selector_messages')

Try_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#devices_get_devices_dev_selector_messages_content > form > div.sandbox_header > input')))
action.move_to_element(Try_btn).click().perform()
```

This code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite
```

...implies that the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance was unable to find the element for one or the other reasons:

- The element haven't loaded properly when you tried to interact with it.
- Element is within an `<iframe>` / `<frame>`
- The style attribute of the element contains **`display: none;`**
- Element is within an *shadow DOM*

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59853448/javascript-error-failed-to-execute-elementsfrompoint-on-document-the-provi/59854498#59854498)

---

### This use-case

Among the 72 elements with text as **Try it out!** i.e.

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Try it out!" data-sw-translate="">
```

barring the desired element all the other 71 elements have an ancestor with `style` attribute set as **`display: none; overflow: hidden;`**. Where as only the desired element is having `style` attribute set as **`overflow: hidden;`**.

to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#devices_get_devices_dev_selector_messages_content input[value='Try it out!']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='devices_get_devices_dev_selector_messages_content']//input[@value='Try it out!']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```