# How to solve testing with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

what could be the error pls in this msg:::
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite.   (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59853448/javascript-error-failed-to-execute-elementsfrompoint-on-document-the-provi)

Comment: Might want to put your code where the error takes place.