# Selenium access span on menuitem not selectable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, webdriverwait

I am using Selenium on Python for scraping.

Based on [javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59853448/javascript-error-failed-to-execute-elementsfrompoint-on-document-the-provi) I've tried to access the second element of the fifth menu item. Selection by id is fine, but menu item seems not to be accessible.
html

```
<li class="k-item k-state-default" role="menuitem">
   <span class="k-link">
      <span class="undefined "i="">Budynki</span></span></li>`
```

Code trials:

```
dataset_drop_down_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@title = 'Informacja o obiektach mapowych']")))`
```

Errors:

```
 dataset_drop_down_element = Select(dataset_drop_down_element)
 Select only works on <select> elements, not on <span>

 dataset_drop_down_element.send_keys('Budynek')
 Message: element not interactable

 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Informacja o obiektach mapowych"]/span[2]').click()
 Message: element not interactable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **Budynki** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://goleniowski.webewid.pl/e-uslugi/portal-mapowy")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@title='Informacja o obiektach mapowych']/span"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@data-role='popup']//li/span/span[text()='Budynki']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```